# Upgrading OSX El Capitan to PHP 7

Tags: composer-php, osx-elcapitan, php-7

I am attempting to use Composer in my Laravel 5.3/Spark/Homebrew environment on my Mac using El Capitan.  The composer script is failing with the following errors:

```
 Problem 1
    - This package requires php >=5.6.4 but your PHP version (5.5.30) does not satisfy that requirement.
  Problem 2
    - laravel/framework v5.3.10 requires php >=5.6.4 -> your PHP version (5.5.30) does not satisfy that requirement.
```

So in an effort to upgrade my installed version of PHP on my Mac, I ran this command:

curl -s http://php-osx.liip.ch/install.sh | bash -s 7.0

I rebooted and checked the version of php

```
PHP 5.5.30 (cli) (built: Oct 23 2015 17:21:45) 
Copyright (c) 1997-2015 The PHP Group
Zend Engine v2.5.0, Copyright (c) 1998-2015 Zend Technologies
➜  ~
```

Any instructions on how I can upgrade the version of PHP on my Mac?

Answer (score 1):

Turns out I needed to simply edit my $PATH.  I am using ~/.zshrc and just needed to add the following:

```
export PATH=/usr/local/php5/bin:$PATH
```